# Trying to read a single character at a time into an array of indefinite size

Tags: c++, arrays, input, struct

I am a CS student working on a c++ project.  We have been instructed to declare a struct and use it to read in an array of chars and keep a tally of how many letters are used in the string.  We are not allowed to use a string; it MUST be an array of our declared struct.
The input must be as long as the user wants; the code has to be able to accept new lines of input and be terminated by '.'
I'm really struggling here.  I don't even know where to begin.  I've thrown together some code as best-guess for what to do, but it crashes after pressing "." then enter, and I don't know why.

```
//declare struct
struct data
{
    int tally = 0;
    char letter;
};

//size of string to read in at a time
const int SIZE_OF_CHUNK = 11;
int main()
{
//input chunk of struct
data    input[SIZE_OF_CHUNK];
int     placemark,
        length;

cout << "Enter sequence of characters, '.' to terminate:" << endl;

do
{
    for (int index = 0; (input[index].letter != '\0') && (input[index - 1].letter != '.'); index++)
    {
        cin >> input[index].letter;
        placemark++;
    }

    //I intend to put something here to handle if the code
    needs to read in another chunk, but I want to fix the crashing
    problem first
}
while (input[placemark].letter != '.');

//print out what was read in, just to check
for (int index = 0; input[index].letter != '\0'; index++)
{
    cout << input[index].letter;
}

return 0;
}
```

I've tried looking up how to read in a single character but haven't found anything helpful to my circumstances so far.  Any tips on what I'm doing wrong, or where I can find helpful resources, would be very much appreciated.

Comment: **Try something simpler first.** How about a program that reads characters until it reads '.'? Something like `char c; while(cin >> c){if(c=='.') break;}`

Comment: You cannot have an array of indefinite size - all arrays are of a known fixed size.   So it's hard to know what you are asking about.

Comment: To specify:  I've been instructed that "Your program should allow the user to enter multiple lines of input by pressing the enter key at the end of each line," and that "limiting the length of the input is prohibited".  I need to find a way to allow the user to input as long an array as they want with as many lines of input as they want.  I cannot impose any sort of limitations on the size of the array, which was why I said "indefinite size".  Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you must use a declared struct?

If you just want to count the number of times a character has appeared, you don't need to store the character; you just need to store the number of times it appeared. So just `unsigned lettersCount[26]`, and each index maps to a letter (i.e. index `0` means `a`, index `1` means `b`). Whenever a letter appears, just increase the count of that index.

You can map a letter to the index by making use of *ASCII*. Every letter is represented by a decimal number that you can look it up at *ASCII table*. For example, the letter `a` is represented by the decimal value 97, `b` is 98 and so on. The number increases successively, which we can make use of. So if you want to map a letter to an index, all you need to do is just `value - 97` or `value - 'a'`. For example, if you read in the letter `a`, take away 97 from that and you'll get `0`, which is what you want. After getting the index, it's just a simple `++` to increment the count of that letter.

Regarding the treatment of uppercase and lowercase (i.e. treat them the same or differently), it'll be up to you to figure it out how to do it (which should be fairly simple if you can understand what I've explained).

Comment: I am specifically required to use a declared struct, yes.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Kronimiciad like one of the comments have mentioned, arrays are fixed size which must be known at compile time. The only way around that is to use `std::vector<char>`, which in your case, `std::vector<data>`.